# xhr net traffic from Flash invisible in Chrome developer tools

Tags: flash, google-chrome

This appears to be a recent thing, might have occurred when I upgraded Chrome. But I am no longer seeing xhr originating from Flash in Chrome network traffic in the developer tools. This was working for me not long ago. I have looked around for the solution but no luck.

I can see xhr originating from Javascript but not Flash. This is not a problem in the other browsers.

Anyone can relate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the HTTP requests are not included in the network tab anymore if you are using any flash player other than Chrome's own pepper flash player.

To enable pepper player, go to chrome://plugins/

If you need to use a debug version of the flash player, then unfortunately you're out of luck. I would advise using a proxy like fiddler or charles to see the HTTP requests.

Comment: Oh really. What's up with Chrome and pepper flash? Pepper flash blows so many chunks. Slow and choppy as hell. Oh well